# How to make the sizes of groupboxes and the contents of a layout uniform

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I have a few groupboxes inside of a gridlayout and also two Vboxlayouts that will contain widgets.
However I'm having trouble with the sizings of the groupboxes and the layouts as the layouts have a smaller horizontal size, what do I need to do to make them uniform?
[image: The result of the UI on the left the UI tree from QT designer on the right]

Comment: share the .ui file

Answer (score 0):

Without much detail to go on in the question, my best guess is that for each `QGroupBox` in Qt Designer you want to set its `sizePolicy` -> `Horizontal Policy` to `Expanding`.  This will make each group box take up the maximum amount of available horizontal space within its parent layout/widget. Which in turn should make them all the same overall width.